# Michael Hartl Tutorial Chapter 6 - Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on Michael Hartl's Tutorial.  I'm on Chapter 6.  I am up to user validation. The code below is what I was told to use, but it doesn't work.  I get the error message `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)`.  I don't see a syntax error. Any suggestions?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  subject { @user }
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end 
  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end 
end
```

Comment: You really need to work on formatting your code. Line things up to make them readable and you'd be able to find your missing `end`

Comment: @nickm: I think you should stop that activity (adding the tag). A similar tag was discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294548/derail-railstutorial-org), some time ago.

Comment: Fair enough @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: @NickM: and now maybe quickly undo the changes, before meta notices? :)

Comment: I removed the tag from the posts I added it to, but I don't have permissions to edit/delete the tag itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  subject { @user }
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end 
  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end # you've missed it
  end # and this one

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end #
  end # and two more    

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you indent your code, that way it'll be much more obvious where `end` keywords should go (and you'll see immediately that you're missing one). *(Hartl does throughout the book.)*

For example:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  subject { @user }
  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should be_valid }
  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

*If the indentation doesn't match up anywhere, **it should jump out at you**, then you'll know there's a problem.*

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, do .. end specifies a block. It goes like:

```
... do

.. Some Code Here ...

end
```

You should indent your code and have better look at the missing end.

In general, Its a convention in Ruby to use 2 spaces Or a tab character with length of 2 spaces to indent your code.